# How to create a array in 2D array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new in c#, I am trying to create a simple array in a 2D array, Em trying following code but getting error,

```
float [,] Tile = new float[17,23];
Tile[0,0] = new float[2] {1,2};
```

em getting error: Cannot implicitly convert type `float[]' to`float'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is right code:

```
 float[,][] Tile = new float[17, 23][];
 Tile[0, 0] = new float[2] { 1, 2 };
```

More information on C# arrays at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`Tile[0,0]` is a single float.

So you should add it like this

```
float [,] Tile = new float[17,23];
Tile[0,0] = 1;
Tile[0,1] = 2;
Tile[1,1] = 1337;
etc..
```

**Edit**
From your comment you can do something like this

```
 float [,][] Tile = new float[17, 23][];
 Tile [0,0] = new float[] {1,2};
```

Comment: but I want to create a array in that 2array index. for eg. Tile[0,0] =  array with 2 indexes

Comment: You should have `new float` rather than `float float`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
float [,] Tile = new float[17,23];
Tile[0,0] = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but your code should be like:

```
    float[,] Tile = new float[17, 23];
    Tile[0, 0] = 1.0f;
    Tile[0, 1] = 2.0f;
```